# Parsing a String and reading each name ( which is newline delimited ) into a list object

Tags: c#

My Goal: The user will select a list of "Appliance names that are newline delimited", I have this code working okay. The problem arises when I try to loop through the list and input them into a new list of type 'Appliance'

```
class Appliance{
  public string name;
  public string Firmware;
  public stirng cpu_10sec;
  public string mem;
}
```

and Here is the code where I attempt to build my "DatapowerList"

```
string f = txt_ListofAppliances.Text;
List<Appliance> DatapowerList = new List<Appliance>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f))
{
  Appliance Datapower;
  While ((Datapower.name = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
     DatapowerList.Add(Datapower);
  }
 }
```

I am getting the error 
"Use of unassigned local variable 'Datapower'

My apologies if this is a newbie question and let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: Why did you tag this Java or C++?

Comment: You have to instantiate Datapower...

Comment: Sorry Luchian, I thought that Java and C++ would be similar..

Answer (score 0):

You have to create instance of `Appliance`.

Change

```
Appliance Datapower;
```

To

```
Appliance Datapower = new Appliance();
```

You can simplify your code to

```
string temp = default(string);
While ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  DatapowerList.Add(new Appliance {name=temp});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx):

```
foreach (var s in File.ReadLines(f))
{
    DatapowerList.Add(new Appliance { name = s });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a couple options at your disposal. In the example you provided, you have to create an instance of your Appliance `Datapower` before you can assign a value to one of it fields:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f))
{
    Appliance Datapower = new Appliance(); //Notice the "= new Appliance()" on this line.
    while ((Datapower.name = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        DatapowerList.Add(Datapower);
    }
}
```

As my personal preference, I dislike assigning values inside of while/if/etc. statements. For me it takes away a small layer of readability from the code. I would do something like the following instead:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f))
{
    while (true)
    {
        string s = sr.ReadLine();
        if (s != null)
        {
            //If the line that was read isn't null, add a new instance of Appliance
            // to the list. You can assign the "name" field a value when you create
            // the instance by using the following format: "new Object() { variable = value }
            DatapowerList.Add(new Appliance() { name = s });
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: lchabod ulwhy now just write string s;
                        
                        while ((s= sr.ReadLine()) != null){ } ..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Like I said in the answer, it's more of a personal preference. I dislike assigning values inside of while/if statements the same way I dislike using `var` for anything other than anonymous types. Sure it compiles, but -for me- it reduces the readability of the code.

Comment: you could assign values / string s out side the while loop you should not use While(true) when you can just use the ReadLine != null but that's your choice..

Comment: Thanks Ichabod for your information, I now have that piece working